# Make a batch file move files from the directory it is running from

Tags: batch-file

How can I make a batch file move files from the directory it is running from? For example code:

```
**move {***CURRENT BATCH FILE DIRECTORY***}\Programs\myfile.txt**
```

What do I replace `{***CURRENT BATCH FILE DIRECTORY***}` with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say *"the directory it is running from"*, I assume you mean the folder that contains the currently executing batch file. If so, then you want `%~dp0`. The expansion will automatically append the trailing backslash.

```
move "%~dp0Programs\myfile.txt" "target folder"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't the "." (dot) work for you? I mean:

```
move .\Programs\myfile.txt
```

Comment: Oh, now I see... you are calling the batch from another dir. You need something like `$(dirname "$0")` from bash.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Windows, if the current directory is where `Programs` is.

```
move "Programs\myfile.txt" "target folder"
```